# Image upload similar to the ebay image upload functionality

Tags: jquery, image-uploading

I want to set the image upload plugin which is used in ebay.com site.
I want to download this plugin.I already searched for this ,but not get yet.
The other oplugins does not have this all features.
If there is any plugin available by this all features.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uploadify` for image uploading.Here is the link http://www.uploadify.com you can also see demos there.

Answer (score 0):

In the year 2017, I have found this to be a great solution:

[jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)